# Haxe doesn’t have the Literal types?

Tags: types, haxe

TypeScript and Python (3.8.x and newer) supports Literal types but looks like Haxe doesn’t (for now).

I need to pass a string to the function without typos like in following code.

TypeScript:

```js
type LiteralStatus = "modified" | "corrupted";

class tsFile {
  status: string;
  constructor() {
    this.status = "new";
  }
  set_status(status: LiteralStatus) {
    this.status = status;
  }
  get_status() {
    return this.status;
  }
}

const file = new(tsFile)

console.log(file.get_status()); // new

file.set_status("modified"); // modified
console.log(file.get_status());

// file.set_status("classified") // Throws an exception because argument is not assignable to parameter
// file.set_status() // Throws an exception because the function was expecting for at least one argument

file.set_status("corrupted"); // corrupted
console.log(file.get_status())
```

Python:

```py
from typing import Literal

class pyFile():
  def __init__(self):
    self.status = "new"

  def set_status(self, status: Literal["modified", "corrupted"]):
    self.status = status
    
  def get_status(self):
    return self.status

file = pyFile()

print(file.get_status()) # new

file.set_status("modified") # modified
print(file.get_status())

# file.set_status("classified") # Throws the TypeError exception
# file.set_status() # Throws the TypeError exception

file.set_status("corrupted") # corrupted
print(file.get_status())
```

What is the best pattern to create these literal types in Haxe?

Comment: Ik know stackoverflow is programming questions related, but [TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TS) ? None of the definition return anything related to programming.  Why use this, and not type the complete name of it?

Comment: @Luuk _“None of the definition return anything related to programming”_ — Come on… _“TypeScript (file extension .ts), a Microsoft programming language”_.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: I know, but I want to prevent everyone from typing PY when they mean Python... 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [enum abstracts](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-enum.html)

```
enum abstract Status(String) from String {
    var Modified = "modified";
    var Corrupted = "corrupted";
}


class File {
    var status:Status = "new";
    
    public function new() {}
    
    public function get_status():Status {
        return status;
    }
    
    public function set_status(status:Status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

function main() {
  final file = new File();
  trace(file.get_status());

  file.set_status(Modified);
  trace(file.get_status());

  file.set_status(Corrupted);
  trace(file.get_status());
}
```

https://try.haxe.org/#95E9203E